# Client not able to send message

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

It's a simple client -server program in which client sends a text and server displays it on the console.This is my code :

MyServer

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class MyServer {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
 {
  ServerSocket socket=new ServerSocket(4444);
  Socket s=socket.accept();
  BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

 String text;
 while(  (text=in.readLine())!=null)
  {  System.out.println(text);
   } 

 }
```

MyClient

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.net.*;


 public class MyClient {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{ Socket socket=new Socket("localhost",4444);
PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
out.println("c:/users/pinder/desktop/happy.txt");



 }
 }
```

The exception occurs in the **readLine()** statement in **MyServer** class.
   This is the  exception that i get :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
at networking.MyServer.main(MyServer.java:25)
```

Comment: questions about why this code does not work are off-topic....

Comment: The program is doing what you would expect it to do.  You haven't explained what the bug is.

Comment: oh really? i expect it to print the message sent by the client but it doesn't . I have mentioned the bug properly

Comment: Hint: Whenever you have a `Closeable` resource you should call `close()` on it if you want it closed cleanly and not get an error.

Comment: When you get an error what do you expect Java to do if not print it?

Comment: Even if i close all the streams it still doesn't print the message

Comment: then for what reason the error is there?

Comment: Ah, I must have missed that in your question.  I assume it was the error you were concerned about.

Comment: @PushpinderSinghGrewal The reason for the error is you didn't close the connection properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `SocketException` is an `IOException` (which is in the `throws` clause of your `main()` method. Since you didn't close the connection properly the reader threw this error and it was printed by the Launcher.

if you `close()` the Socket when the other end is reading the connection you won't get this error. e.g.

```
public class MyServer {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        try (ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(4444);
             Socket s = socket.accept();
             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()))) {

            String text;
            while ((text = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(text);
            }
        }
    }
}
public class MyClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 4444);
             PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream())) {
            out.println("c:/users/pinder/desktop/happy.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

If I run MyServer and then MyClient, the server prints

```
 c:/users/pinder/desktop/happy.txt
```

Comment: Yeah it works.Thank you !